# On the asymptotics of the Chebyshev psi function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

Denote by $\psi(x)$ the Chebyshev psi function over prime powers. Assuming the RH, it can be shown via the Riemann explicit formula that

$$\psi(x)-x \ll √x  |\sum_{|\gamma| < T} \frac{1}{\rho} | + O(1)$$, where the sum is over the complex zeros $\rho$ of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ with imaginary part $|\gamma| < T$. Let $N(T)$ denote the number of such zeros. Since $N(T)\ll T\log T$, it follows from the above that

$$\psi(x) - x \ll √x (\log T)^2.$$.

Montgomery-Vaughan, in their famous text "Multiplicative Number Theory" on p.419, then take $T=x$ and deduce that

$$\psi(x) - x \ll √x (\log x)^2.$$

*My question is, what motivates this choice of $T$ ? Is there anything special about it ?*

Comment: The error term in the explicit formula is not $O(1)$ but rather $O(\frac{x \log^2(xT)}{T} + \log x)$ (in fact, something slightly better can be said - see p. 400 in Montgomery-Vaughan).  The sum $\sqrt{x} (\log T)^2 + \frac{x \log^2(xT)}{T}$ will always be of order at least $\sqrt{x} (\log x)^2$, and $T=x$ gives this order (also other choices, such as $T=x^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha>1/2$). So $T=x$ is special but not that special.

Comment: @Ofir, maybe am missing something, but doesn't the $O(1)$ term come from the explicit formula itself ? Recall that $\psi(x) = x - F(x, T) - \log 2\pi - (1/2)\log(1-x^{-2})$, where $F(x, T)$ denotes the sum over the complex zeros ?

Comment: The explicit formula in your last comment is false. The RHS only converges to $\psi(x)$ as you let $T\to\infty$.